# How to ignore the dynamic value in the JSONPath Expression of SoapUI while only validate against the rest complete payload?

Tags: json, soapui, json-path-expression

I want to validate the JSON response of all key value pair except the timestamp which is Dynamics. Either I have to write multiple JSONPath Expression assertions or can achieve this in one assertion?

Only want to ignore timestamp value match and rest all should match.

[image]